# Merge into object array from object by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My goal is to update an object array by matching an `id` with another object containing a matching key to update the object array's `value` key.

Working with an object array like:

```
const objArr = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Activity Attendance',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '2000',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'activity_attendance'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Total Number of Interacted Consumers',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '400',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'total_number_of_interacted_consumers'
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Booth Location',
    type: 'Select (Single Answer)',
    value: '',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'booth_location'
  }
];
```

And an object like:

```
const obj = {
  '6': '1500',
  '123': '180',
  '140': ''
};
```

Desired outcome:

```
const objArr = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Activity Attendance',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '1500',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'activity_attendance'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Total Number of Interacted Consumers',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '180',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'total_number_of_interacted_consumers'
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Booth Location',
    type: 'Select (Single Answer)',
    value: '',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'booth_location'
  }
];
```

I have started down the route of mapping the `objArr`, but am not sure of how to proceed to make the "match" within `obj` to get the correct value to update. My failing attempt:

```
objArr.map(i => i.id.includes(Object.keys(obj).map(o => Number(o))));
```

How can I can merge into an array of objects from an object?

Comment: Are you okay with modifying the original `objArr` or are you deliberately wanting to create a new array?

Comment: I am ok with modifying the original `objArr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using `map()` function and spread (`...`) operator:

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Activity Attendance',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '2000',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'activity_attendance'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Total Number of Interacted Consumers',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '400',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'total_number_of_interacted_consumers'
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Booth Location',
    type: 'Select (Single Answer)',
    value: '',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'booth_location'
  }
];

var obj = {
  '6': '1500',
  '123': '180',
  '140': ''
};

console.log(objArr.map(i => ({
  ...i,
  value: obj[i.id] ? obj[i.id] : i.value 
})))
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are okay with modifying the original array, this will do the trick:

Just loop through the original object and check if there is an update

```
objArr.forEach(o=>{
    if( obj[o.id] )
        o.value = obj[o.id]
});
```

Example:

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Activity Attendance',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '2000',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'activity_attendance'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Total Number of Interacted Consumers',
    type: 'Number',
    value: '400',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'total_number_of_interacted_consumers'
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Booth Location',
    type: 'Select (Single Answer)',
    value: '',
    nameChanged: false,
    typeChanged: false,
    internalName: 'booth_location'
  }
];

var obj = {
  '6': '1500',
  '123': '180',
  '140': ''
};

// loop through the array of objects
objArr.forEach(o=>{

    // see if there is an update in the `obj` var
    if( obj[o.id] )
        o.value = obj[o.id] // apply the update
});

console.log(objArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript I would do something like this

```
objArr.forEach(element => {
  let value = obj[parseInt(element.id)];
  if(value){
    element.value = value;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (which doesn't modify the original value of `objArr`):

```
const result = objArr.map(o => Object.keys(obj).includes(o.id.toString()) ? Object.assign(o, {value: obj[o.id]}) : o);
```

- `Object.keys(obj).includes(o.id.toString())`: check whether in `obj` is an entry with a key corresponding to an `id` in `objArr` (see [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))
- `Object.assign(o, {value: obj[o.id]}) : o)`: if so, create new a object with the value in `objArr`, but override `value` (see [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)). If not, return the same object.

Demo:

```js
const objArr = [
  {
    id: 6,
    // ...
    value: '2000'
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    // ...
    value: '400'
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    // ...
    value: ''
    // ...
  }
];

const obj = {
  '6': '1500',
  '123': '180',
  '140': ''
};

const result = objArr.map(o => Object.keys(obj).includes(o.id.toString()) ? Object.assign(o, {value: obj[o.id]}) : o);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to solve your problem:

```
objArr.forEach(i => i.value = Object.keys(obj).includes(String(i.id)) ? obj[i.id]: i.value);
```